# PHP Array removing the duplicate values

Tags: php, arrays, double

My relationships table looks like this:

```
`relationships` (`relationship_id`, `relationship_individual`, `parent_id`, `partner_id`) VALUES
(28, 160, 161, NULL),
(29, 161, 163, 162),
(30, 162, NULL, 161),
(31, 163, NULL, 164),
(32, 164, NULL, 163),
(34, 166, NULL, 165),
(36, 165, NULL, 166);
```

I would like to display partner only once. I trie to do so:

```
foreach($tree as $child) {
    foreach($tree as $c) {
        if($child['relationship_individual'] != $c['relationship_individual'] && $child['partner_id'] == $c['relationship_individual']){
        unset($tree[$child['partner_id']]);
        }
    }
}
print_r($tree);
```

But it doesn't work, nothing happens. What should I do?

Comment: What exactly is the content of the $tree array? And also, on the example that you gave, there is no repeat on the `partner_id` col.

Comment: Have you tried `print_r($tree)` before starting your loop? Maybe `$tree` doesn't contain what you think it contains.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could explain how the different entities are related, in particular relationship_individual, parent_id, partner_id and what you are trying to achieve. Do you have a hierarchy, does it have a fixed depth or not. If the depth is unlimited, then nested loops will not do. You will need a recursive function.

Comment: Most likely you answer lies in changing your SQL query rather than your PHP.  Can you please explain the table, what is meant by the different relationships and what you desired query output is?

Comment: Yohan, Leafheart the array contains the data from the table I posted above and you're right there's no repeat on the partner_id. The data repeats when I try to print partners as 161 is the partner of 162 and 162 is the partner of 161. GreatBigBore, it contains the data, it must be something else. Tarik, I'm trying to display a family tree, each individual can have parent and partner, if parent has a partner, individual has both parents. It doesn't have fixed depth and I use a recursive function. It's not all the code. I wrote this function to understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the duplicates, but when fetching them you may want to execute a DISTINCT MySQL query.

[MySQL DISTINCT Help](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)